# Как выбрать сообщения в ListView из базы данных с помощью CursorAdapter для создания списка диалогов?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, cursoradaper

Имеется база данных sqlite, содержащая таблицу с сообщениями, которая периодически синхронизируется с глобальной базой данных.

Из нее производится выборка

```
Cursor loadInBackground(){
    Log.d("[MESSAGES QUERY]", MessagesTable.STATUS + sortByStatus
            + " AND " + MessagesTable.DATE + sortByDate);
    return helper.getReadableDatabase().query(MessagesTable.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{MessagesTable.ID, MessagesTable.BODY,
                    MessagesTable.DATE,
                    MessagesTable.FROM, MessagesTable.TO,
                    MessagesTable.STATUS},
            MessagesTable.STATUS + sortByStatus + " AND "
                + MessagesTable.DATE + sortByDate,
            null, null, null, null);
```

и загружается в `ListView` с помощью `CursorAdapter`

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.changeCursor(data); 
}
```

В программе выводится список сообщений. По клику на любой элемент списка, пользователь переходит в чат.

И сейчас, собственно, назрела идея выводить не весь список сообщений, а список диалогов - только последнее для каждого собеседника.

**Собственно вопрос, как это лучше реализовать?**

Можно ли составить выборку последнее сообщение по дате для каждого уникального id собеседника, если количество и id собеседников заранее неизвестны? А ведь еще при поступлении нового сообщения, нужный элемент списка нужно удалить и добавить обновленный вверху списка. Как это принято делать? Очень не хочется изобретать пяти колесный велосипед, задача вроде типовая.

Answer (score 2):

`view` - представления, очень хорошо работают, обновляются сами при записи нужных данных в основные таблицы

сделай на окно списка диалогов `view` c сортировкой по дате, и на экран конкретного диалога тоже делай `view`, можно даже временный.